# how to make widget movable in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

**Hello World!**
I try to make this Movable on the side of the screen .

[in this image I try to make this button Movable , that I want to could user move it in side of the screen to make it easy to access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YB5M.jpg)
my code like this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../../../core/utils/styles/button.dart';
class BtnShowTypesOfApartments extends StatefulWidget {
  const BtnShowTypesOfApartments({super.key,required this.onPressed});
  final void Function()? onPressed;
  @override
  State<BtnShowTypesOfApartments> createState() => _BtnShowTypesOfApartmentsState();
}

class _BtnShowTypesOfApartmentsState extends State<BtnShowTypesOfApartments> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
        style: outlineButton,
        onPressed: widget.onPressed,
        //                              Container(height: 50,width: 100,color: Colors.white,),
        child: Container(
            padding:
            const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 4),
            height: 35,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: const Text(
                " صنف السكن ")));
  }
}
```

**Note:** I don't want to make this widget on center , just side by side on the screen that two option right or left and up or down in this same time

Comment: you can try this: https://pub.dev/packages/draggable_widget

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable-class.html